# Oops, try again. Your function failed on the message yes. It returned 'yes' when it should have returned 'Shutting down'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Here is my pyhton practice program:

```
def shut_down(s):
    return s

    if yes():
        shut_down("Shutting down")
    elif no():
        shut_down("Shutdown aborted")
    else:
        shut_down("Sorry")
```

the question given to me are:

1. if the shut_down function receives an s equal to "yes", it should return "Shutting down"
2. elif s is equal to "no", then the function should return "Shutdown aborted".
3. if shut_down gets anything other than those inputs, the function should return "Sorry"

Comment: what's the problem or error you're getting?

Comment: return s will return before s is processed?

Comment: Both your first post and your edit have many misunderstandings - you really need a Python tutorial much more than an answer from StackOverflow can help with.

Comment: This really looks like some last-minute panic on your homework.

Comment: The if else statement is never reached because of your return statement at the beginning.

Comment: @harshil9968: this is my error: Oops, try again. Your function failed on the message yes. It returned 'yes' when it should have returned 'Shutting down'

Comment: @iCode: yes i am doing an online course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points:

- Misplaced return statement. Should be at end.
- `if yes():` It is wrong. You want to compare function input with yes. It should be `if s == 'yes':`. Same for rest also.
- Since you have written function definition as `def shut_down(s):`, it is expecting one argument. You should pass one argument while calling this function as `shutdown(yes)`
- Once you called function and since your function has return statement, it will return some value, which you should catch like `ret = shutdown(yes)`

```
def shut_down(s):

    if s == "yes":
        r =  "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no":
        r =  "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        r = "Sorry"
    return r


ret = shut_down("yes")
print (ret)
```

Comment: def shut_down(s):
    
    if "Yes":
        s = "Shutting down"
    elif "No":
        s = "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        s = "Sorry"
    return shut_down // updated like this and got it. thanks for the support

Answer (score -1):

something shorter than the best answer:

```
def shut_down(s):

    if s == "yes":
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no":
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"

print shut_down("algo")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "Yes":
        return s == "Shutting down"
    elif s == "No":
        return s == "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return s == "Sorry"
```

Answer (score -3):

As others pointed out in comments your return should at the logical end of your function.

```
def shut_down(s):

    if s == "yes":
        r =  "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no":
        r =  "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        r = "Sorry"
     return r
```

Comment: What about  if yes():  and if no():

Comment: Oops I dint notice that.

Comment: Don;t you think : instead of only if "yes": it should be if s == 'yes': ?

Comment: i have updated the code like this:                                                                                                                       def shut_down(s):
    
    if yes():
        shut_down("Shutting down")
    elif no():
        shut_down("Shutdown aborted")
    else:
        shut_down("Sorry")
    return s          // Now the error is : Oops, try again. Your shut_down function should take one parameter.

Comment: @DineshPundkar yes it should, My bad instead if trying running the complete code I just looked for the error he is getting and tried to fix that.
It was so trival that I havent even tried running the code

Comment: @saurabhbaid:  got the output when updated like this//  def shut_down(s):
    
    if "Yes":
        s = "Shutting down"
    elif "No":
        s = "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        s = "Sorry"
    return shut_down //thanks for the support